# Can't rewrite a folder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, web

I have moved hoster lately, but I have made a slight change in the directory. I renamed a folder from "listing" to "vendors". I used this code below to prevent a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^listing/(.*) vendors/$1
```

This didn't worked for me. What can I do to fix this problem?

Old URL:

```
http://www.oldsite.com/curacao/listing/chinese-culture-club/
```

New URL:

```
http://www.newsite.com/curacao/vendors/chinese-culture-club/
```

This is the full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^listing/(.*) vendors/$1

# BEGIN WPSuperCache
# END WPSuperCache
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Comment: In which directory is the .htaccess?

Comment: Most likely the interpretation of `.htaccess` is not yet enabled.

Comment: @arco444 in the root

Comment: @arkascha I am on a internship right now and working on a wordpress project. In the .htaccess were already some rewrited codes. I am not really familiar with .htaccess, maybe the code isn't good which I wrote

Comment: Ah, there already are other rewrite rules. Then most likely that is the issue. Please post the full `.htaccess` style file.

Comment: @arkascha see edited question

Comment: The rule before yours will match before your rule is considered. A question of the order of the rules.

Comment: If it's at the root then I think the leading `^` should also be removed as the request will look like `curacao/listing/...`

Comment: @arco444 That didn't worked for me :(

Comment: You will need to also take on board the comment from @arkascha about the placement of the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^listing/(.*) vendors/$1
> ```

There would seem to be more wrong with this than is covered in the comments. For a start, your example URLs have a change of host/domain, but this is not reflected in this directive. Or whether `oldsite.com` and `newsite.com` are hosted at the same place (I assume they are). Also, what you posted is an *internal rewrite*, but you probably need an *external redirect* in order to correctly resolve the 404 (otherwise you end up with what is essentially *duplicate content*).

Try, the following, before your existing *internal rewrites*, at the top of your `.htaccess` file. As a general rule, *external redirects* should always come before *internal rewrites*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(curacao)/listing/(.*) http://www.newsite.com/$1/vendors/$2 [R=302,L]
```

You only need one `RewriteEngine` directive, preferably at the top of your file. (It can be anywhere, but it's more logical at the top.)

The `$1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which is just "curacao" in this case, but it avoids repetition. And $2 is a backreference to the second capture group, much like you had before.

The `R` flag indicates an external *redirect* (the absolute URL in the *substitution* is also likely to trigger an external redirect anyway, but would default to a 302). The `L` (`last`) ensures no further mod_rewrite directives are processed during this pass.

If this should be a permanent redirect, then change the `302` (temporary) to a `301` (permanent). 301s are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic.